# Develop In C++ For Windows CE In Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, windows-ce

How i can develop and compile command line C++ programs in my Linux Ubuntu, for my Jornada 720 that have a Windows CE 3.1(HPC 2000), something like a compiler like that for Palm or something like *gcc*, and a tutorial of development and compiling will be very nice, remember that i want to build command line programs to Windows CE, programs that runs under the *cmd* of the Windows CE. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [CeGcc](http://gizguides.wikidot.com/linuxcegcc).

Comment: But in my Windows CE 3.1(HPC 2000) i have to use the Mingw32ce, that is the the  CeGcc page. Thanks!